# Change the Status of a Sales Order in ExactOnline

Tags: php, json, api, exact-online

We currently need to set the status of orders to CANCEL in ExactOnline through the API when they are cancelled in our shop.

I got through the ExactOnline API documentation and in the **PUT** request of **salesOrders**, I did not find any **Status** field that I can update but this field exists when this is a **GET** request. https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=SalesOrderSalesOrders

My PUT request would have this body as status 45 = Cancelled.

```
{
    "Status": 45
}
```

Which currently returns "204 No Content" (which is normal) BUT the status is not updated.

What would be the workaround then?

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably a question for Exact Online support. We can't access further Exact Online documentation without a login account, but the page you've linked to does not have a status on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some inquiry and discussions with ExactOnline team, updating the status of sales related things through API is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the PHP API client? https://github.com/picqer/exact-php-client if your API request is malformed, this might be an easier way to do it.

Comment: It's not about a wrong request or something. It's just about the fact that the Status field does not seems to be there in the PUT request.